# Automatically update single cell value (not entire range) - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

**Description**

In my workbook there are three sheets where the user can input or change data.

Currently, when a user chooses 1 out of 4 options in a dropdown-list manner in column C the corresponding value is outputted in column D. The user can then change the value in column D as intended.

I've used the following code to automatically update the value in column D based on the value in column C in each of the three sheets:

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 3
    Call Macro1
End If   

If Target.Column = 4
    Call Macro2
End If

End Sub
```

**Problem/Desired output**

When the user changes a specific/single value in column C only the corresponding value in column D should change, not the entire column in all three sheets.

Is it possible to restrict the automatic update to a specific cell?

(Please let me know if I need to upload the entire code for the values generated in column C and D in order to provide me with a hint/solution).

Comment: You will need to pass the target range into the other code.  otherwise how are the other code supposed to know which row in column D should be updated.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I've inserted **Code** in each of the three sheets and the code that populates the values in a dropdown-list maner in column C and the corresponding values in column D in a Module that loops over C and D.

Answer (score 0):

You could add code to the `ThisWorkbook` module to monitor all three sheets.

I've no idea what the corresponding value in column D should be so this code will just copy the value in column C over to column D.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        'Column D is updated to show same value as col C.
        Target.Offset(, 1) = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `ByVal Sh As Object` do?

Comment: That's a reference to the sheet - only important if you need to know what sheet you're on.  For example, if you wanted the code to run on Sheet1 & Sheet2, but not Sheet3 you could use `If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Or Sh.Name = "Sheet2" Then`

Comment: Ah, I see. But I assume your code still updates the entire range/column D instead of just updating a specific cell? Should I somehow add your code in the Module?

Comment: The code will update only the cell to the right of the cell you changed - so change C3 will updated D3, etc.  `Target` is a reference to the cell, `Target.Offset(,1)` is a reference to the cell 1 column to the right (offset by 1 column).  The code should be pasted in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

Comment: Do I need to copy the code in the Module that does the data transformation from column C to D in each sheet? Or do I need to copy your code above in the Module and if so how?

Comment: No, the code just goes in the `ThisWorkbook` module.